# How to i get marker moved vector2 on google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have to show marker without use google map api marker.

So i use html canvas api but it's hided problem occurred. it's marker's vector2D(lat, lng) logic is not accurate

I tried a few stuff

1. Way to compare difference in the center coordinates before and after the movement in window.onmousemove, google.addEventListener("drag") and obtain the "px" value.
2. Way to calculate the value of the visible marker on the map based on lat and lng in the upper left corner every drag, or onmousemove event.

they are not accurate

Markers drawn on canvas should be moved exactly the same as markers drawn using google map api.

please let me know how to get vector accuratly..

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this issue. Also please do read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question, leading to more people able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
it works fine when use `center_changed` event
not `drag`, `onmousemove` and other else